# django category list (parent child)

Tags: django

I have a category list with parent - child relationship:

```
class Categories(models.Model):
  cat_name = models.Charfield()
  cat_parent = models.ForeignKey('self')
```

So i want to list them as such:

```
Category 1
  Sub category 1
  Sub category 2
  Sub category 3
Category 2
  Sub category 4
  Sub category 5
```

etc...

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this so

```
categories ={}

map(lambda c: categories.setdefault(c.cat_parent, []).append(c),\
    Categories.objects.filter(cat_parent__isnull=False)\
        .select_related('cat_parent'))
```

And you will get `categories` dict like

```
{
    Category 1 : [Sub category 1, Sub category 2, Sub category 3],
    Category 2 : [Sub category 4, Sub category 5]
}
```

Then in your template

```
{% for category, sub_categories in categories.items %}
    {{ category.name }}
    {% for sub_category in sub_categories %}
        {{ sub_category }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Wain then how do i replace my return statement, which is currently t = loader.get_template('bla'); c=context('cat_list',cat_list);return HttpResponse(t.render(c))

Comment: You should change just this line `c=context('cat_list',cat_list);` to `c=context('categories',categories);`

Answer (score 4):

depending on your actual use case, this may be overkill, but have a look at [django-mptt](http://django-mptt.github.com/django-mptt/), (Modified Preorder Tree Traversal), a library which simplifies dealing with hierarchical data using a sql database (and, in this case, django)

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this:

```
class Categories(models.Model):
  name = models.Charfield(max_length=255)
  category = models.ManyToManyField('self', blank=True)
  is_parent = models.BooleanField()

  def __str__(self)
     return self.name
```

This way you can store both parent and sub in the same model set and reference them back to a parent. Then on your ViewSet you could do the below code to return the parent dict:

```
queryset = Category.objects.filter(is_parent=True)
```

Looks something like this:

```
{
    "name": "Parent Category",
    "category": [
        "1",
        "2",
        "3",
        "4",
        "5",
        "6",
        "7",
    ],
    "is_parent": true
},
{
    "name": "Parent Category 2",
    "category": [
        "8",
        "9",
        "10",
    ],
    "is_parent": true
},
```

Hope it helps, it sure helped me.